# Send audio stream from microphone to Google Speech - Javascript

Tags: node.js, websocket, streaming, getusermedia, google-speech-api

I am trying to send microphone input at the client(nuxt) side to the node + socket.io server and then to the google speech api. I am getting stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })` and send it to back end using socket.io-stream. My client side code as follows.

```
import ss from 'socket.io-stream'

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((mediaStream) => {
  ss(this.$socket).emit('audio', mediaStream);
});
```

And my server code as follows.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3555);
const ss = require('socket.io-stream');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient({ keyFilename: 'key.json' });
  const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
  const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
  const languageCode = 'en-US';
  const request = {
      config: {
          encoding: encoding,
          sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
          languageCode: languageCode,
      },
      interimResults: true,
  };
  ss(socket).on('audio', (stream) => {
    const recognizeStream = client.streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', data => {
        process.stdout.write(
          data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
            ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
            : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
        );
    });
    stream.pipe(recognizeStream);
  });
});
```

But this code doesn't work and display the error `TypeError: stream.pipe is not a function`.

Someone please point out the error or tell me a way to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this out?